# How do I use NuGet to install ChartJS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, chart.js, nuget-package

When I had been manually installing ChartJS into my web application before, I would just insert the following script tags:

```
<script src="./js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./js/utils.js"></script>
```

But now that I am using NuGet to install the ChartJS "package", I have no idea where it is located or how to include it in my pages. How do I reference it? I have searched the folders after "installing" ChartJS using NuGet Package Manager into my solution and cannot find the Chart.bundle.js or utils.js files.

Comment: Nuget has ChartJS and Chart.Js both are different which one are you after?

Comment: I did not resolve it. I installed it manually without using NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I use NuGet to install ChartJS?

You should use `npm` or `bower` to install `Chart.js` package (Not the `ChartJS`). That because **the usage of NuGet for css/javascript libraries is discouraged.**

When you open the [project site](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html) of the `Chart.js` package, it also recommend you to get the `chart.js` via `npm` or `bower`:

[image]

Detail to get it via `npm` or `bower`:

Select project and add a new file to the project root. While in the template manager (`Add->New File...`), search for "Bower Configuration File" or "npm Configuration file".

Then edit the file and add your dependency, i.e.

package.json (npm):

```
{
    "dependencies:" {
        "chart.js": "2.7.2"
    }
}
```

bower.json (bower):

```
{
    "dependencies:" {
        "chart.js": "2.7.2"
    }
}
```

Once you save, the file will be downloaded in a directory named `node_modules` (npm) or `bower_components` (bower) in your project file `.csproj` folder, then you can use it by script, like:

```
<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.js"></script>
```

Besides, when you open the nuget package `Chart.js` with nuget package explorer, you will find it only includes a Content\Scripts directory inside its NuGet package which contains a `Chart.js` and `Chart.min.js`. So if you want to get `Chart.bundle.js` and `utils.js`, please try to get it by `nmp` or `bower`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that Bower is now discouraged: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/